# Make the ios app working in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the `pitch detection code` from `demetri miller`  [demetri miller pitch detection](http://demetrimiller.com/2011/01/25/pitch-detection-in-ios-4-x/) in my application. I want the microphone to work in background and give a `UILocalNotification` on a particular pitch.

How to make the application run in background.
Currently when the app is in background is there way to make it work fully.

Answer (score 1):

Use the NSTimer when app is going from foreground to background start NSTimer and every one second your timer method will call and you can check the application state. you can execute every thing fine.

```
   NSTimer *timerBackground = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(YourMethod:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timerBackground forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: How to check if the application is going from foreground to background??

Comment: Can we do something in applicationdidEneterBackground

Comment: Yes you can check that method will call in appdelegate

Comment: I am not that familiar with ios. Sorry to ask anything foolish. In my appdelegate i will use the applicationdideneterbackground function to activate the timer. But since my functions are in viewcontroller.how to call these methods from this part.. Also is there something like background app refresh feature on ios 7 we can use

Comment: I am using microphone. so will it run in background?

Comment: For the 3 rd comment you can use NSNotificationcenter so that you can able to call the viewController object methods